# Is it possible to change an annotation inside @Nested?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a Service with @Autowired, but I want to change the annotation to @MockBean inside a @Nested class, is it possible?
I tried this, but it didnt work

```
public class SessionTokenServiceTest extends AbstractBaseTest {
   @Autowired
   private TestService testService;

   @Nested
   class nestedClass {
      @MockBean
      private TestService testService;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with that? Is this problem related to the type of annotation you use or is the question about if there can be an annotation at all or how to access it?

Comment: I have some test classes that need the testService to be Autowired, but some other classes (inside Nested) need it to be MockBean.